# How to avoid "The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content" warning in nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt app in mounted() method I do reading data from localStorage and commit them in app storage.

```js
mounted() {
  const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'))
  if (basket) {
    this.$store.commit('setBasket', basket)
  }
}
```

this lead to warning *The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content*

I found solution:

```js
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'))
    if (basket) {
      this.$store.commit('setBasket', basket)
    }
  }, 100)
}
```

Now no warning in console. If timeout value 0 or 10 instead 100 ms - then warning in console again

Is there a more graceful way for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`client-only`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component) component can be helpful here, since this code is client side only.

Wrap the basket received items in your template like this

```html
<client-only>
  <my-basket-items><my-basket-items> <!-- coming from the localStorage -->
</client-only>
```

On top of that, this a really great article talking about those kind of issues: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/vue-hydration-error/

Comment: Thanks, @kissu, I tried but it not helped me. I wrapped in <client-only> whole basket component and parts of this component. No effect for me
UPD: I found a problem. State data loaded from localStorage used not only basket, but in another components too